# Discord Bot - MessageEmbed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am very new to javascript and I don't understand a lot of the actual code.
However, I have one query, how can I make the "cahbResponses" appear in a MessageEmbed?
I've looked at the literature on MessageEmbeds from the Discord JS guides but I still have no clue.

The code I am working on is:

```js
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.author.bot) return;
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
 var args = message.content.substring('!'.length).split(' ');
 switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
  case 'cahb':
   var response =
    cahbResponses[Math.floor(Math.random() * cahbResponses.length)];

   message.channel
    .send(response)
    .then()
    .catch(console.error);
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
});
```

Comment: Where is `cahbResponses` defined? Is the code throwing you errors?

Comment: I have ```const cahbResponses = [``` further up in the code but because it has hundreds of responses I simply cut it out of my question. On that, is there a better way to store hundreds of responses? At the moment it's just a long long list below that line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are importing Discord

```js
// you probably have this on the beginning of your file
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

Then

```js
var response = cahbResponses [Math.floor(Math.random()*cahbResponses .length)];

// Create a MessageEmbed object and set the description
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(response);
// Then send the embed
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Read other `MessageEmbed` methods and properties here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed